# Why this error?

Tags: java, osgi-bundle

I am following the simple tutorial in bundTools http://bndtools.org/tutorial.html
I created an empty BND project.but Iam getting this error in the build of bnd.bnd:

> Adding a sourcepath that is not a directory: /usr/local/AT_Dev_Env/Amritam/ARUNS ECLIPSE/Workspace/org.example.api/src

That is a directory for sure.

Thanx

Comment: Just stabbing blindly: try with a path not having a space... I know it sounds ridiculous, but I'd try it

Comment: @ppeterka 66 :tried...noluck..